# Angular two way binding is not working [(NgModel)]

Tags: angular

In angular code trying 2 way binding using model. But encountered error message while loading the page.
**ErrorMessage**: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined  at RegisterComponent_Template (register.component.html:6).

register.html

```
      <form #registerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register()" autocomplete="off">
      <h2 class="text-center text-primary">SignUp</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" 
      [(ngModel)]="model.username" placeholder="username">

       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" 
      placeholder="password">
      <p> You entered {{model.password}}</p>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
     <button class="btn btn-success mr-2" type="submit">Register</button>
     <button class="btn btn-default mr-2" type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
     </div>
    </form>
```

register.ts

```
  import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AccountService } from '../_services/account.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
@Output () cancelRegister = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { }
  model:any;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    
  }


  register() {
    this.accountService.register(this.model).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.cancel();
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
  cancel() {
    this.cancelRegister.emit(false);
  }

}
```

Comment: model is declared any and no data is available. You should either initialize the model in the ngOnInit() or set it to something before loading the template? For example the model should have a property username

Comment: @A2la updated the code still facing error: ngOnInit(): void {

    this.model.username="user";
    this.model.password ="password";
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the `ngForm` variable `model` not being initialized.
In your ngOnInit try initializing it like

```
this.model = {  userName: '', password: '' };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your model from `model: any` with:

```js
model: {
  username: string;
  password: string;
} = {
  username: '',
  password: ''
};
```

And now, you can try again.

Comment: That only changes the type, not the actual value inside the property though. You further need to *initialize* it as typed object. On the other hand, I assume OP tries to manipulate `this.model` inside the `register()` method of `AccountService`, which brings other issues.